# Insert a single value to the entire column from a form

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i have a question about handling form from html to php. I just want to put a inputed decimal number (Longitude / Latitude) into each Longitude and Latitude Column i have in my Sql Table. Here I go :

[image: My Mysql table]

I have a form like this :

```
<form action="hitung.php" method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data"><fieldset><legend>Input Parameter Petir Klien Di bawah:</legend>
<table bordercolor="#FF0000" border="1"><caption>Tabel Input Lokasi Koordinat Klien</caption>
<tr><td>Isikan Longitude Lokasi Klien</td><td>:</td><td><input type="number" **name="long"**  placeholder="Isikan nilai Longitude berupa Desimal" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Isikan Latitude Lokasi Klien</td><td>:</td><td><input type="number" **name="lat"**  placeholder="Isikan nilai Latitude berupa Desimal" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="submit" name="klien" value="HITUNG DATA"/></td></tr>
<tr><td>
</td></tr></table></fieldset></form>
```

and here is my " hitung.php " i made :

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
include 'koneksi.php';

$longitude=$_POST['long'];
$latitude=$_POST['lat'];
$datalat = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT latitude FROM ngx");
$datalong = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT longitude FROM ngx");
$arraylat= mysqli_fetch_array($datalat);
$arraylong= mysqli_fetch_array($datalong);

while($longitude=$_POST['long']  && $latitude=$_POST['lat']) {

$lats= $arraylat['latitude'];
$longs= $arraylong['longitude'];

$update= mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO ngx (long, lat) VALUES ($lats, $longs)");}
?>
```

And i want to add an entire column of " lat " and " long " in my Query Table with a same single value that re created from the form above (exactly from the input text of lat / long), ***so that the entire row in lat column will be inputed by input text of lat and the entire row in long column will be inputed by input text of long from that form***

Please, im still new with programming... Would you sincerely help me out? Thank you so muuch.

Comment: It looks like your table already contains columns called `longitude` and `latitude`, and they already have values. It's not clear what you want them again with `long` and `lat`? Is it a different value, relating to a different location, which must go in the long and lat columns? If not, it looks like repetition.

Comment: `LONG` is a mysql reserved word.

Comment: *"Would you sincerely help me out?"* - Help you out "how"? You didn't say what it was that you want to achieve here. Have you read any of the comments or tried the answer given?

Comment: Yeah, but i have 4 column of coordinates actually. 
Longitude and latitude (i have found a code to import it from .csv file), and the other is lat and long which is inputed from my form. I want to calculated them later with a math formula... Thank you

Answer (score 1):

`INSERT` is for adding new rows to the table. To change columns in existing rows, use `UPDATE`.

Also, you shouldn't be using `while`. Your loop condition doesn't change, so the loop will run forever.

If you just want to set the `long` and `lat` columns from the form, there's no need to fetch the `longitude` and `latitude` columns first.

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
include 'koneksi.php';

$longitude=$_POST['long'];
$latitude=$_POST['lat'];

$update= mysqli_prepare($con, "UPDATE ngx SET `long` = ?, `lat` = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($update, "dd", $longitude, $latitude);
mysqli_stmt_execute($update);
?>
```

I've also shown how to convert your code to a prepared statement, to protect against SQL injection.

Note that you need backticks around the column name `long` because it's a reserved keyword. It's usually a bad idea to use reserved words as column names because of this.

Comment: Is `ff` a typo? And UPDATE without a WHERE will cause their db to be entirely updated.

Comment: No, I just didn't remember the correct code for floats, and assumed it was f rather than d.

Comment: I thought he does want the entire table to be updated.

Comment: I don't know, they'd have to tell you or you to ask them. Btw, I know you added ticks around the reserved word (as stated in a comment up there). You probably should add that to your answer, should any of my comments happen to have disappeared for some odd and weirdly reason unknown to us.

Comment: The question says "entire column" and he circled that in the picture.

Comment: "Entire column" could also mean everything belonging in the same record data. The question's unclear for me for all of this, so I'll just place my vote and see what happens.

Comment: Look at the picture, he marked the columns in every row. He wrote **And i want to add an entire column of " lat " and " long " in my Query Table with a same single value**. It seems perfectly clear to me.

Comment: Right ye are matey, right you are. I stands corrected!

Comment: Thank yoi very much , guys, i ll try this code of yours, Barmar